# nalgebra convention about roll pitch yaw

Tags: rust, nalgebra

I write small ray tracer to learn rust language. I decided to use nalgebra as library for vectors and so on.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=79c13e8cf2725d2398dcf1fac61c047c
From that example you can see that roll rotate over X but my expectation was that roll should rotate over Z. I didn't find the nalgebra convention in the documentation. Is it possible for someone that use the library to point me to that convention and to tell me if it is possible to change it trough cargo config

Answer (score 1):

Nalgebra apparently uses this definition for rotation:

[image: Roll/Pitch/Yaw]
(Picture from another answer on SO)

So your (0,1,0) vector is rotated 90 degrees around the X axis and thus becomes (0,0,1).

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a link that that answer and are you aware if I can switch that behavior with cargo settings